# How to authenticate from java/ldap wtih Windows Group Managed Service Account (GMSA)

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

We have a java application which currently uses a single Active Directory account (username + password) to do the following:
- Run application as a Windows Service
- Authenticate with SQL Server through jdbc
- Query/scan AD using LDAP

A customer is asking if we can support Group Managed Service Accounts (GMSA).  I can't seem to find any mention of how to do this here or other sites.  Can someone give me some hints on the last 2 items in the list?  Is the LDAP authentication just a matter of additional parameters being given?  Or a totally different method?

We are using unbound for LDAP access.

Answer (score 0):

We have had similar problems using the UnboundID LDAP SDK, as well as Spring LDAP, to do a LDAP bind to a gMSA. After a lot of trial and error I found a solution. A quick rundown of the solution: A .Net console application to extract the password and decrypt it, the writing it to the output to be able to read it from a Java application. Then using a DIGEST-MD5 bind we are able to bind to the gMSA user. More info about all of this can be found in this post:

https://sourceforge.net/p/ldap-sdk/discussion/1001257/thread/bb0f55349f/

Comment: While link shared may answer question, but it is always recommended to give proper code snippets and explanation while answering any question

Answer (score -1):

Since you asked for **hints** (not the answer) and I don't know which security framework you're using, I can at least give you one hint:

Search for `Spring Security Framework`. They have options so you can use LDAP, AD and other authentication types.

Comment: Thanks for the "hint" :) but we are not using Spring.  We are using unbound for LDAP.